# Do bestow count toward cards that say "when [sub-type] enters on the battlefield"

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

[Champion of the Parish](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Champion%20of%20the%20Parish) gains +1/+1 "Whenever a another human enters the battlefield under your control". If I play [Nyxborn Shieldmate](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Nyxborn%20Shieldmate) as a bestow does it count toward this effect? I know it does not count as a creature but it is still a human is it not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the definition of "Bestow" ([702.102a](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_20140201.txt)), the card will enter as an Aura spell.

> "Bestow [cost]" means "You may cast this card by paying [cost] rather than its mana cost." and "If you chose to pay this spell’s bestow cost, it becomes an Aura enchantment and gains enchant creature.

The game will remove the `Creature` type from the card. Since `Human` is a subtype of `Creature` and not a subtype of `Aura`, the card loses the `Human` subtype per [205.1a](http://media.wizards.com/images/magic/tcg/resources/rules/MagicCompRules_20140201.txt)

> "If an object's card type is removed, the subtypes correlated with that card type will remain if they are also the subtypes of a card type the object currently has; otherwise, they are also removed for the entire time the object's card type is removed."

The ability won't trigger since the card does not have the subtype `Human`.

Comment: I agree with your conclusion but I think the crucial rules are 205.3m and 205.3k. It's too long to post here but they state enchantment subtypes and creature subtypes, which then supports to your conclusion that as an Enchantment-Aura type it cannot have the creature subtypes. I already knew it was not a creature but your use of the phrase "creature subtypes" gave me a clue of where to look.

Comment: The other relevant rule is 205.1a: "If an object's card type is removed, the subtypes correlated with that card type will remain if they are also the subtypes of a card type the object currently has; **otherwise, they are also removed for the entire time the object's card type is removed**." Bestow temporarily removes the Creature type.

Comment: @murgatroid99 are you saying that "becomes an Aura" implies "loses creature and gains enchantment and Aura"?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thanks for posting 205.1a I will update the answer.

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, I am. Unless an ability that changes types says "in addition to its types" or "still a [type. supertype, or subtype]", the other types are removed. See rule 205.1b.